# "setstate" in vanilla javascript, enforce changes

Tags: javascript

I am new to Js, and i am coding a simple quiz app with HTML, CSS and JS to learn.

I am a mobile developer and use Flutter and Dart, dart is pretty similar to JS. On the quiz app, when someone presses the next button after an answered question, i want it to switch to the next question.

When the user presses the button nothing happens... In dart i would use the setState method, which forces the UI to reload with the updated changes. Is there an equivalent method in JS? I found that setState is used in ReactJS, however this is coded in vanilla Js.

I have an Array of 2 questions (which are maps containing the questiopn text, answer alternatives and correct answer). Then I have an integer variable which is the questionIndex. So first question the index i 0, and when the user presses the next button ( to go to the next question) it should increment by 1.

Here is the code for the button click:

```
function onClickNext() {
    console.log("called");
    
    currentQuestionIndex++;
    
}
```

the Array of questions:

```
const questions = [
  {
    question: "What is the capital of Sweden?",
    "alt 1": "Stockholm",
    "alt 2": "Gothenburg",
    "alt 3": "Malmö",
    "alt 4": "Linköping",
    correctIndex: 0,
  },
  {
    question: "What is the capital of England?",
    "alt 1": "London",
    "alt 2": "Manchester",
    "alt 3": "Bournemouth",
    "alt 4": "Cardiff",
    correctIndex: 0,
  },
];
```

And here are the dynamic HTML components (the question + answer alternatives, which are suppoosed to change when next is pressed, so it moves onto the next question.

```
document.getElementById("question").innerHTML =
  questions[currentQuestionIndex]["question"];
button1.innerHTML = questions[currentQuestionIndex]["alt 1"];
button2.innerHTML = questions[currentQuestionIndex]["alt 2"];
button3.innerHTML = questions[currentQuestionIndex]["alt 3"];
button4.innerHTML = questions[currentQuestionIndex]["alt 4"];
```

Would be really thankful for some guidance, and also if someone knows a way to make my code more consise and efficiant.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since Vanilla JS has no `state listeners` that will update the DOM automatically, you can program this yourself, for example:

```
function onClickNext() {
    console.log("called")
    
    currentQuestionIndex++
    drawQuestionScreen()
    
}

function drawQuestionScreen(){
   document.getElementById("question").innerHTML =
      questions[currentQuestionIndex]["question"];
   button1.innerHTML = questions[currentQuestionIndex]["alt 1"];
   button2.innerHTML = questions[currentQuestionIndex]["alt 2"];
   button3.innerHTML = questions[currentQuestionIndex]["alt 3"];
   button4.innerHTML = questions[currentQuestionIndex]["alt 4"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just populate the question HTML anew after calling `onClickNext` so that the reassignment has an effect.

To make the code more concise, save the question at the current index in a variable first, instead of accessing through the index each time.

```
const questionDiv = document.getElementById("question");

const populateQuestion = () => {
  const question = questions[currentQuestionIndex];
  questionDiv.innerHTML = question.question;
  button1.innerHTML = question["alt 1"];
  button2.innerHTML = question["alt 2"];
  button3.innerHTML = question["alt 3"];
  button4.innerHTML = question["alt 4"];
}

// populate on pageload:
populateQuestion();

// and also on click:
function onClickNext() {
  currentQuestionIndex++;
  populateQuestion();
}
```

An even better approach would be to use an array for the buttons and answers instead of separate property and variable names. Consider naming the array of possible answers `answers` instead of `alt`, it'll probably make more sense at a glance.

```
const populateQuestion = () => {
  const question = questions[currentQuestionIndex];
  questionDiv.innerHTML = question.question;
  question.answers.forEach((answer, i) => {
    buttons[i].textContent = answer;
  });
}
```

You should also consider using `.textContent` - only use `.innerHTML` when deliberately inserting HTML markup.